# Get screen coordinates of a vertex in a THREE.js Points object using bufferGeometry

Tags: three.js, projection, buffer-geometry

I want to have a DOM node track a particle in my THREE.js simulation. My simulation is built with the Points object, using a bufferGeometry. I'm setting the positions of each vertex in the render loop. Over the course of the simulation I'm moving / rotating both the camera and the Points object (through its parent Object3d).

I can't figure out how to get reliable screen coordinates for any of my particles. I've followed the instructions on other questions, like [Three.JS: Get position of rotated object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699811/three-js-get-position-of-rotated-object), and [Converting World coordinates to Screen coordinates in Three.js using Projection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586527/converting-world-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates-in-three-js-using-projection), but none of them seem to work for me. At this point I can see that the calculated projections of the vertices are changing with my camera movements and object rotations, but not in a way that I can actually map to the screen. Also, sometimes two particles that neighbor each other on the screen will yield wildly different projected positions.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
const { x, y, z } = layout.getNodePosition(nodes[nodeHoverTarget].id)

var m = camera.matrixWorldInverse.clone()

var mw = points.matrixWorld.clone()

var p = camera.projectionMatrix.clone()

var modelViewMatrix = m.multiply(mw)
var position = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z)
var projectedPosition = position.applyMatrix4(p.multiply(modelViewMatrix))
console.log(projectedPosition)
```

Essentially I've replicated the operations in my shader to derive `gl_Position`.

`projectedPosition` is where I'd like to store the screen coordinates.

I'm sorry if I've missed something obvious... I've tried a lot of things but so far nothing has worked :/

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: any chance you can add create a fiddle reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z)

var projectedPosition = position.applyMatrix4(points.matrixWorld).project(camera)
```